# how to set a eyelid drive shapekey

Tags: rigging

[image]

[image]

This is what I am doing right now.
I watch a lot of YT videos. someone says this, someone says that.
And I try every set they teach, and NO SHIT happens!
I even don't know which step is right or wrong.

I am gonna crazy right now.
Anyone can help?

Comment: Can you make a copy of your blend file and reduce it to the eye, the area around the eyelid and the eyelid and shapekeys, and the bone(s) you want to use to control the shapekey? If you do that we could maybe take you step by step through the process.

Comment: Thanks  I add the eye picture.

Comment: Marty Fouts asked for a small example blend file that you could share because it's hard to tell from images only -- What exactly does not work? What happens when you rotate the eye bone? Is the bone roll (axis) correct? Is the driver triggered?

Answer (score 2):

Did you notice that I asked you for a *blend file* but you pasted a screen capture instead?  I think the problem you are having is that you need to follow tutorials *exactly* until you have a working example and you're not doing that.  I'm going to give you another example tutorial.  Follow it until you've done it right, as a way to practice solving your problem.

Here is an extremely crude eye in an extremely crude eyelid with a very simple rig.  The `eye` bone isn't even relevant.

[image: extremely crude eye in an extremely crude eyelid with a very simple rig]

Here is what it looks like when the `top lid` bone has rotated to "close" the eyelid -- using an extremely crude shape key that doesn't even keep the lid entirely out of the eye.

[image: extremely crude eyelid closed by rotating the rig bone.]

Here's a crude screen capture showing the lid opening and closing as the bone moves.

[image: screen capture of the lid opening and closing as the bone moves.]

And here's how to make it work:

Here's a blend file without the driver.  Follow the steps below and you'll be able to reproduce what I've done

[image]

It's nice for the animator that the `top lid` bone is centered at the center of the eye and that the bone just touches the "eyelid" but it doesn't matter. Here's what does matter:

- Notice the bone's axis.  The important thing is that we want the rotation to be on the X axis.  The bone has been aligned so that the X axis matches the world's X axis, but note that the Y axis lies along the line of the bone.
- With the bone in *Pose Mode* switch the rotation to XYZ Euler and lock everything but the X rotation:

[image: The bone's transforms in Pose mode showing XYZ Euler and everything but X rotation locked.]

- Hover over the X Rotation field and right click, bringing up this menu:

[image: The menu that pops up when you right click on X rotation.]

- Select *Copy as New Driver*.
- Go to object mode and select the object that has the shape keys.  I've named mine *eyelid*.
- Go to the Properties editor, the *Object Data Properties* tab, the *Shape Keys* panel and select the shape key that controls the closing shape.  I've named mine *upper eye close*
- Hover over the shape key's value field and right click.  Select *Paste Driver* from the menu.  The field will turn purple.

[image: The menu that comes up when right clicking over the Shape Key input.]

- Hover over the field and right click again.  This time pick *Edit Driver*.  A popup like this will appear.  I've put a red box around the field you will need to change.

[image: Driver editor popup with Type field selected]

- Change the *Average Value* field to *Scripted Expression*. That will cause a new field will appear. I've put a red box around it.

[image: Driver editor showing scripted expression field]

- In that box change `rotation_euler` to `rotation_euler * 2`.

That's it.  Now you have a driver that when you rotate the `top lid` bone in *Pose* mode will cause the shape key to gradually be applied.

### Brief Explanation

The exercise of copying the Rotation as a driver and then pasting it on the *value* field of Shape Key sets up a relationship between the two.

The exercise of editing the driver changes that relationship.

When those two steps are done, rotating the bone on its X axis will cause the Shape key's value to change between 0 and 1, causing the shape key to be applied.

That's the basis of adding drivers.  Practice until you understand it before trying anything more complex.

Comment: omg. you are so nice and good and kind!!! Thank you very much!!!!